# Bad Request Issue with Manual Trigger Input but testing is successful

Tags: power-automate, common-data-service

I had a child-flow that was working.
I changed some of the input parameters using the usual Power Automate editor.
I then went and adjusted the 2 flows that called this child flow.

When testing this child-flow, it is successful.
When the other 2 flows try and call this flow, there is an error:

```
"code":"TriggerInputSchemaMismatch","message":"The input body for trigger 'manual' of type 'Request' did not match its schema definition
```

The sub flow has this warning message which might be the problem, however when I try and fix the problem there is no information to assist me.

[image]

**Full input to the trigger of the flow is as follows**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "title": "CompleteByDateTime",
      "type": "string",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Please enter your input",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "TEXT"
    },
    "text_1": {
      "title": "TaskScheduleGuid",
      "type": "string",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Please enter your input",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "TEXT"
    },
    "text_2": {
      "title": "AssignedToGuid",
      "type": "string",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Enter the GUID of the User to assign the 1st to.  Null if defaulting to the default user/team instead.",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "TEXT"
    },
    "boolean": {
      "title": "CheckForDuplicate",
      "type": "boolean",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Please select yes or no.  Will match on the Schedule Type and DateTime.  If duplicate found, this flow ends.",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "BOOLEAN"
    },
    "text_4": {
      "title": "AssignedToGuid2",
      "type": "string",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Only applicable if CreateSecond is true.  Enter the GUID of the User to assign the 2nd to.  Null if defaulting to the default user/team instead.",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "TEXT"
    },
    "boolean_1": {
      "title": "CreateSecond",
      "type": "boolean",
      "x-ms-dynamically-added": true,
      "description": "Please select yes or no",
      "x-ms-content-hint": "BOOLEAN"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "text",
    "text_1",
    "boolean",
    "boolean_1"
  ]
}
```

I'm completely stuck and frustrated.  I don't want to have to build this entire flow from scratch!

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the webhook `Content-Type` in Power automate was set to `application/json` however a postman request was set the `Content-Type` to `plain/text`. Changing this fixed the issue for us.

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Changed-a-table-s-header-s-name-But-Flow-keeps-getting-errors/td-p/803550

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the calling the child-flow and receiving 400 responses.  The child-flow identified itself as broken.

Some of the INPUTS to the child flow were not mandatory (optional).  However, when trying to pass a null string, the caller of the child flow was getting an error. Enough of these 400 Bad Requests passed toward this child-flow caused that Fix message to appear.  However, none of it was very clear.

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Changed-a-table-s-header-s-name-But-Flow-keeps-getting-errors/td-p/803550